# Problema al deployar backend en Railway

Tags: nodejs, deployment, nestjs

Quiero deployar mi backend en Railway, en la consola de railway no me da ningun error, pero cuando quiero abrir el link me dice Application failed to respond.

Le agregué el puerto de la variable de entorno que provee Railway y nada... El tema es que con backends mas simples si me deja subirlo sin problema
Les dejo el codigo del main

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0');
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: config.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'),
        port: config.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
        username: config.get<string>('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
        password: config.get<string>('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        database: config.get<string>('DATABASE'),
        logging: true,
        logger: 'file',
        synchronize: true,
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        ssl: true,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    UserModule,
    PrendaModule,
    CarritoModule,
    CompraModule,
    MercadoPagoModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: EmailInUseExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```